# Way to vertically and horizontally align in tabular?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to type a niceish looking Cayley table and have been having trouble with two aspects. The first is simultaneously aligning the cell contents vertically and horizontally. It seems I can only do one but not the other? I saw other answers suggest using \tabularx but when I try to add this with my preamble it says it conflicts with my geometry package.

Here is the best I've managed to get it so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.4cm}|m{0.4cm}|m{1.85cm}|m{2.5cm}|@{}m{0cm}@{}}
\hline
$*$ & $|0\rangle$ & $\omega$ & $\xi$ & \\ [1ex]
\hline
$|0\rangle$  & $|0\rangle$ & $\omega$ & $\xi$ & \\[1ex]
\hline
$\omega$  & $\omega$ & $\xi-2\omega$ &$\frac{41}{16}\xi-\frac{165}{32}\omega$ & \\[3ex]
\hline
$\xi$  & $\xi$ & $\frac{41}{16}\xi-\frac{165}{32}\omega$  & $\frac{1673}{256}\xi-\frac{6765}{512}\omega$ &\\[3ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Additionally, is there an easy way to shade the top row and first column to make them standout?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Are you trying to make the contents of all cells vertically and horizontally aligned? `tabularx` would not really help with either, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The goal is to have the contents of each cell centered horizontally and vertically. Sorry for not being clear.

Also it seems there is a bug when using $m{ cm}$ on the final column, which is why in the above I've added a dummy column of sorts at the end.

Comment: By the way, loading `tabularx` with `geometry` works fine. I don't think it would help here, but it shouldn't conflict. I use this all the time.

Comment: I checked through and it appears to load now, not sure what the problem was earlier. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the height with struts, here I define `\mms` (medium math strut) for a `\vphantom{\Big|}` and `\bms` (big math strut) for `\vphantom{\bigg|}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\mms}{\vphantom{\Big|}}
\newcommand{\bms}{\vphantom{\bigg|}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{|>{\columncolor{gray!30}}c| *{3}{c|}}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\mms * & |0\rangle & \omega & \xi \\
\hline
\mms |0\rangle  & |0\rangle & \omega & \xi \\
\hline
\bms \omega  & \omega & \xi-2\omega &\frac{41}{16}\xi-\frac{165}{32}\omega \\
\hline
\bms \xi  & \xi & \frac{41}{16}\xi-\frac{165}{32}\omega  & \frac{1673}{256}\xi-\frac{6765}{512}\omega \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks perfect! However when I generate this in my code some of the column and row borderlines disappear in the grey cells, is this due to the method I'm using to generate the pdf?

Comment: @AXidenT In these cases, pixel rounding at small magnification may mask the rules, check at large magnification.